# Qt background color of row in ListStringModel

Tags: c++, qt

i try set color of row with this code and it doesnt work.

```
    QColor dataColor =Qt::red;
    row = seznamChyb->rowCount();
    seznamChyb->insertRows(row,1);

    QModelIndex index = seznamChyb->index(row);
    ui->listView->setCurrentIndex(index);

    seznamChyb->setData(index,dataColor, Qt::BackgroundRole);
    seznamChyb->setData(index,data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what really type of `seznamChyb` and `ListStringModel`. But Changing the background color of row required the implementation of method `QAbstractItemModel::data()`.

I write a example for this question, and it does work well:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class StringListModel : public QAbstractListModel
 {
 public:
     StringListModel(const QStringList &strings, QObject *parent = 0)
         : QAbstractListModel(parent), stringList(strings) {}

     int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
     {
        return stringList.count();
     }
     QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
     {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            return stringList.at(index.row());
        if (role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole && index.row() == 0) // Look this.
            return QBrush(Qt::red);
        else
          return QVariant();
     }

 private:
     QStringList stringList;
 };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableView tableView;

    QStringList list;
    list << "a" << "b" << "c";
    StringListModel model(list);

    tableView.setModel(&model);
    tableView.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Please check your program again.

Comment: `seznamChyb->insertRows(row,1);` ==> `seznamChyb->insertRows(row,0);`
or `seznamChyb->index(row);` ==> `seznamChyb->index(row, 1);`

Comment: if i change 0 for 1 or add 1  it doesnt write text and backgrout its white again

Comment: no idea what's going on. please have a look at my example code. and check your code again.

Comment: thx but i use this predefined ListStringModel class and i dont reimplemnt any function and i dont now how reimplemnt it.